# Magento Catalog URL rewrite show 404 error

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I recently upgrade magento 1.3 to 1.8 .Now catalog Url rewrite is not working.It just shows **404 page not found error**.Anybody knows what is the reason.Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is Fixed.

I just run the below query on my db.

```
INSERT INTO `report_event_types`
    (`event_type_id`, `event_name`, `customer_login`) 
VALUES
    (1, 'catalog_product_view', 1),
    (2, 'sendfriend_product', 1),
    (3, 'catalog_product_compare_add_product', 1),
    (4, 'checkout_cart_add_product', 1),
    (5, 'wishlist_add_product', 1);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, but your solution is not helping, because the values are already in the table. What else can I try?